# How to unit test an HTTP delete with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I have a simple ViewSet to represent a model in my database, defined as such

```
class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet)
```

I have the following code to unit test an HTTP GET request:

```
    client = APIClient()
    client.credentials(username="test", password="test")
    response = client.get("/api/events/")
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertEqual(len(response.data), 2)
```

My question is this: How do I make the same type of test, but for HTTP delete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [`rest_framework.test.APIClient`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apiclient), you can use `.get()`, `.post()`, `.put()`, `.patch()`, `.delete()`, `.head()` and `.options()` methods.

```
data = {...}
response = client.delete("/api/events/", data=data)
```